# Android scrollview not displaying strings

Tags: java, android, layout, initialization

The following class is intended to display a set of strings contained in an xml file. Within the onCreate method, an array of strings is pulled from a resource file. These strings are a set of corny jokes that are added to an ArrayList of Joke objects (m_arrJokeList), constructed from the strings.

The addJoke method, called within the onCreate method, is intended to display these jokes in a scroll view as text. However, none of this seems to work on either my device or emulator, so something is definitely wrong with the code. I'd like to know how I can fix this as well on some tips on how to work with these views.

Here is the code, **not fully implemented**.

```
package edu.calpoly.android.lab2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SimpleJokeList extends Activity {

        // Contains the list Jokes the Activity will present to the user
        protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrJokeList;

        // LinearLayout used for maintaining a list of Views that each display Jokes
        protected LinearLayout m_vwJokeLayout;

        // EditText used for entering text for a new Joke to be added to m_arrJokeList.
        protected EditText m_vwJokeEditText;

        // Button used for creating and adding a new Joke to m_arrJokeList using the
        // text entered in m_vwJokeEditText.
        protected Button m_vwJokeButton;

        // Background Color values used for alternating between light and dark rows
        // of Jokes.  
        protected int m_nDarkColor;
        protected int m_nLightColor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstance);
            initLayout();
            Resources localRsrc;
            localRsrc = this.getResources();
            ArrayList<Joke> jokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>(); 
            String[] jokeStrings = localRsrc.getStringArray(R.array.jokeList);

            int size = jokeStrings.length;
            Joke tempJoke = new Joke();
            for(int i=0;i < size;i++)
            {
                tempJoke.setJoke(jokeStrings[i]);
                jokeList.add(tempJoke);
                addJoke(tempJoke);
            }
        }


        // Method used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the Layout
        // for this Activity. 
        protected void initLayout() {
            // TODO
            //LinearLayout rootLayout;
            m_arrJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>();
            m_vwJokeLayout = new LinearLayout(this); // why pass "this"
            m_vwJokeLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            ScrollView extendedView = new ScrollView(this.getApplicationContext());
            extendedView.addView(m_vwJokeLayout);
            setContentView(extendedView);

        }

        // Method used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the Event
        // Listeners which will respond to requests to "Add" a new Joke to the list. 
        protected void initAddJokeListeners() {
            // TODO
        }

        // Method used for encapsulating the logic necessary to properly initialize
        // a new joke, add it to m_arrJokeList, and display it on screen. 
        // @param strJoke
        //            A string containing the text of the Joke to add.
        protected void addJoke(Joke jk) {
            m_arrJokeList.add(jk);
            TextView textJoke = new TextView(this);
            textJoke.setText(jk.getJoke());
            m_vwJokeLayout.addView(textJoke);
        }
    }
```

Comment: put Joke tempJoke = new Joke();  in for loop           for(int i=0;i < size;i++)             {    Joke tempJoke = new Joke();             tempJoke.setJoke(jokeStrings[i]);                 jokeList.add(tempJoke);                 addJoke(tempJoke);             }  then try it. and let me know what happen.

Comment: @user370305 That actually fixed it, should have made that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I answered it, Please mark as a correct so it helps you and also for other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
Joke tempJoke = new Joke();
```

in for loop

```
for(int i=0;i < size;i++) 
{ 
  Joke tempJoke = new Joke(); 
  tempJoke.setJoke(jokeStrings[i]); 
  jokeList.add(tempJoke); 
  addJoke(tempJoke); 
}
```

then try it. and let me know what happen.

Comment: What happened..it fixed everything in a single go. Thanks.

Comment: In your code you are just intializing the object of Joke only once and in for loop you are using the same object so it override the whole values and you just get the either last value or null. so every time initalizing the new object in for loop add different objects in jokeList. and you can access whole list.